# Access the parent Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindow from the contained System.Web.UI.Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radwindow

The question is in the title :

I have a `System.Web.UI.Page` contained in a `Telerik.Web.UI.RadWindow` and I can't find out a way to access the `RadWindow` from the `Page` code-behind.

I tried to explore the `Page` properties, and I guess that there's a casting to do on a control at some point, but I didn't find anything.

**EDIT** : At runtime, I have no clue on where the RadWindow comes from (it is generated dynamically from about anywhere in the application), so I can't access it to modifiy the RadWindow definition. That's why I need to access it at runtime, to alter it programmatically.

Can you help me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the RadWindow in the code-behind of the content page. That would be equivalent to accessing Default.aspx from SomeOtherPage.aspx in the code-behind. There simply isn't a way to do that.

You can, however, use JavaScript. If the pages are all yours (i.e. same application, same domain) you can get a reference to the RadWindow and use its Client-side API. See here:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-radwindow-methods.html

and

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-programming-calling-functions.html - the GetRadWindow() will return the reference

and here

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/window-application-is-page-in-radwindow.html

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Thanks anyway, I'll try to manage with JS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an `xname` to your RadWindow.

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Name="myWindow">
...
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Then you can access `myWindow` in the code-behind of whatever xaml this is in.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, at runtime, I have no clue on where the RadWindow comes from, so I can't access it to modifiy the RadWindow definition. That's why I need to access it at runtime, to alter it programmatically.

Comment: @X.L.Ant How do you not know where it comes from? You must have made it. You can modify it at run time exactly how I've described. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: I mean that the application generates radwindows programmatically at maybe a hundred different places, each time with different params. What you described implies that I access each and every radwindow generation process to add this parameter (not at runtime), which seems unrealistic in my case. At the time the page loads, it can be contained by any of these RadWindows, without knowing which one.

Comment: @X.L.Ant Then perhaps you need to have some kind of observable collection of these windows so you can actually access them. Maybe give each one some kind of unique identifier. It's difficult to answer your question without more detail.